# Windows 7 - Visual Studio 2012 - What else do I need to install for SharePoint developement

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I did a google search for what is the bare minimum I need on my windows 7 enterprise in order to develop against SharePoint 2010. I don't want to install the whole shabang of SharePoint Server 2010 and Foundation 2010.

Every links that I came across suggest to install the entire SP (with SQL). Is there a bare minimum (like just install SharePoint 2010 foundation) that I can install to develop SharePoint solutions using visual studio.

Please suggest.

Also, I like to know the best to stress test for a particular site collection. There are hand full of site collections that performs really poor. (i know this could be what all is on the landing page). I think there is a Visual Studio way or some tool that can measure the performance of the webparts and so forth for a given site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are on the wrong track. You *have* to install SharePoint in order to develop for it (unless you are happy with some edge scenarios utilizing CSOM only; however, these are quite limited in SharePoint 2010).

While it's possible to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7, I highly discourage this approach. It's just more pain than gain. The best option is to build a dedicated virtual machine for SharePoint development. The minimum configuration is Windows Server 2008, and SharePoint 2010 Foundation. You can install it as a standalone server, and keep SharePoint's bundled SQL Server Express to avoid separate SQL Server installation. However, do keep in mind SharePoint is a hungry beast, so you will need *at least* 8 GB of RAM in your host machine even for the minimum config.

Comment: Say, I have a separate VM for development. Will I be able to stress test using VS against production farm or staging farm?

Comment: By stress-testing you mean standard web load testing? I have no experience with VS's load testing capabilities, but usual load testing software should do the job. However, do not expect to be able to execute anything remotely from VS in a distant test / prod farm. There are no remote development scenarios possible with SharePoint.

Comment: makes sense. Do you know any open source load test tool? few of the sites are performing poor and I need to find out exact reasons for that.

Comment: so how would find out why a site is performing poor? Is there a tool for that?

Comment: Well that depends on a ton of factors. First, specify to yourself what "poor" means, what symptoms you are experiencing. Also, consider whether you have any customizations in place (such as any web parts developed by you or third parties) etc. If you can't track down the problem to its root cause, you should open a new question here on SO or on sharepoint.stackexchange.com, describing what you've did and discovered so far.